# abstract classes and validation methods

Tags: php, oop, parent-child, abstract

Introductory OOP question for you:

**Situation:** I want an abstract class with a public setter and abstract validator, since each child will validate that property in a unique way.

**Code:**

```
abstract class Parent {
    public function setName($name) {
        if (validateName($name)) {
            $this->_name = $name;
        } else {
            // error msg
        }
    }

    abstract public function validateName($name);
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public function validateName($name) {
        // ensure name gits this child's requirements
    }
}
```

**Question:** is this a "legal" design approach? I figured since the `setName` method will be the same for every child class, it should be a public method in the parent class, but the validator should be abstract to force child classes to implement it.

I'm just sketching this out on paper conceptually...

Comment: People are used to dumbing down their examples so that others can get to the root of the issue quickly. Usually this is great, however with questions asking about best OOP practice, it becomes pivotal to know what the exact context is. Classes are meant to represent *things*; without knowing what those things are, there is nothing to design a class for.

Comment: In law, legal tries to match with just. In physics, legal can be a chainsaw murderer who attacks orphanages. Legal in programming is much more like the legal in physics.

Comment: There's really not that much more to it, though I appreciate your feedback below. A little more data would be that the `Parent` class is a generic game class, and we want to set the winning side. Child `GameA` only has 2 sides, so valid winning sides would be 1, 2, or 0 (a draw). `GameB` supports 8 players, and there can be a draw, individual winners, or winning teams of 2 or 3 people. So, I want to define the setter in the parent and let the children dictate the validation. That seemed logical to me, but I've only just dipped my pinky toe into OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a valid approach, although your syntax in imperfect:

```
        if (validateName($name)) {
```

should be this:

```
        if ($this->validateName($name)) {
```

But if this is the scope of the architecture, why not just define abstract `setName()` that validates and sets it?  Like this:

```
interface Parent {
    public function setName($name);
}

class Child implements Parent {
    public function setName($name) {
        if (/* $name is valid */) {
            $this->_name = $name;
        } else {
            // error message
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I use an interface here, because there's no code in Parent.

But please realize, this depends on how you're program is structured.  I'd have to see at least a diagram of the program's architecture to say definitely either way.

Comment: Hi Jonah. Thank you for answering. Could you please clarify your suggestion that starts with `why not just...` -- I didn't catch your meaning.

Comment: That change has different meaning, Jonah, but I'm not saying it's wrong. In the original, the parent enforces the procedure in which the parameter is set (and the method should be defined as final). With your change, the child is required to set the parameter (or elect not to) in whichever way it wants. Hopefully this helps clarify the difference, Andrew Heath.

Comment: I understand the interface-derived alternative Jonah presents now that there is some sample code present. In any case, he answered my original question and offered an additional point of thought. Thank you to both of you!